# Import Mathjs in Ionic React leads to Uncaught TypeError

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework, mathjs

I would like to use mathjs in my Ionic react project.
I've installed the library by using `npm install mathjs`.
Now I'm trying to use the library with the following code from the mathjs website:

```
import { sqrt } from 'mathjs'
console.log(sqrt(-4).toString())
```

As well as:

```
import { create, all } from 'mathjs'
const config = { }
const math = create(all, config)
console.log(math.sqrt(-4).toString())
```

But I'm always getting an error:

```
Fraction.js:9 Uncaught TypeError: Object.defineProperty called on non-object
    at Function.defineProperty (<anonymous>)
    at createFractionClass.isClass (Fraction.js:9:1)
    at assertAndCreate (factory.js:35:1)
    at resolver (import.js:243:1)
    at Object.get [as Fraction] (object.js:211:1)
    at import.js:240:1
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at resolver (import.js:228:1)
    at Object.get [as typed] (object.js:211:1)
    at import.js:240:1
```

How can I solve it? Thanks!